# Issue with compiling Opengl and glut

Tags: c, opengl, glut

i am trying to compile a program on my imac, that runs neural network using opengl and glut.
i am using framework for mac to compile opengl and glut but still i get this error. i have a feeling that i am missing some library to compile.

Here is the output:

```
$ gcc gpu.c -o gpu -lfann -lm -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_copyMaskToTexture", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
  "_copyVectorToTexture", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
  "_copyWeightsToTexture", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
  "_destroyLayer", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
  "_generateLayer", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
  "_init", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
  "_initOpenGL", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
  "_printLayer", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
  "_run", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
     (maybe you meant: _run_time)
  "_setInput", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
  "_setOutput", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
  "_test", referenced from:
      _main in gpu-cb634f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not including the proper code or library.

It *looks* like your code is related to the [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html_latest/files2/gpu-txt.html) library, but the linked page says:

> The code is still expremental and is not included in the FANN library but is available for the user to try out if he wishes.

So, your `-lfann` won't help to get these functions defined, you need something else.

Comment: Thats right experimental version, but i am trying. i cant figure out whats missing librrary there. i am using opencl version of fann http://leenissen.dk/fann/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=658&start=0, that includes separate GPU src files that uses shaders using openGL.